# There is no continuous surjective multiplicative map from $M_n(\mathbb H)$ to $\mathbb H$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quaternions

Let $\mathbb H$ denote the field of quaternions. I would like to prove that there does not exist any function $f:M_n(\mathbb H)\rightarrow \mathbb H$ for $n\geq 2$ that is continous surjective and multiplicative.

I have been thinking about this problem for a while but I can't find any contradiction assuming that such a function does exist. I tried considering preimages for $1,i,j,k$ and toying with them, I also tried infering the values of some specific matrices (the $\lambda I_n$, the nilpotent matrices, etc...) but I couldn't reach any conclusion. Mostly, I fail to see how to make use of the continuity here.

Would somebody have a hint as to how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: How is the situation different from the case where we replace $\mathbb{H}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Ok, I see the answer to my own question above. This problem is very nice! What if we weaken 'surjective'  all the way down to 'not identically zero'. Do you still think the map does not exist in that case, or is there an example?

Comment: Do you know about representations of Lie groups?  If so, restrict such a map to get a representation of $GL_n(\mathbb H)$ over $\mathbb H$.  Tensoring over $\mathbb C$ gives a 2-dimensional complex representation of $\GL_{2n}(\mathbb C)$.   This must be reducible if $n > 1$, which contradicts surjectivity.

Comment: @Kimball I see how you get a 2-dimensional complex representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{H})$ and hence of its subgroups such as $Sp(2n)$. But how do you extend it to the bigger group $GL_{2n}(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: There used to be a very good answer, due to ThorstenK to the question in my second comment. Somehow it disappeared so I will reproduce it here. There is a multiplicative non-zero map by composing the embedding of $Mat(n, \mathbb{H})$ into $Mat(4n, \mathbb{R})$ with the determinant and the embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and remarks concerning this problem. I am no expert in the theory of representations of Lie groups, so I am asking the same question as Vincent. Also, I do not see how reducibility of the representation would contradict surjectivity.

Comment: It would be nice to know the subgroup structure of $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$. By dimension considerations the kernel of the map $f: GL(n, \mathbb{H}) \to GL(1, \mathbb{H}) \cong SU(2) \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ must be pretty big and when the only pretty big subgroup of $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$ turns out $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$ itself we get a contradiction with surjectivity. However I could not find much information on $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$ as a group on the internet and the somewhat similar group $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ does have a fairly big subgroup in the form of $SL(n, \mathbb{C})$ so that doesn't bode well...

Comment: @Vincent Thank you Vincent for these explanations, I understand the argument now.

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment because there was a mistake. It is true that 2-dimensional reps are a direct sum of two one-dimensional ones, but for $GL(m, \mathbb{C})$ these need not be trivial (they need to be trivial on the subgroup $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$, that's what confused me. However: since the representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ decomposes as a sum of the action on two one-dimensional subspaces we have that the matrix in $\GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ that a matrix in $\GL(2n, \mathbb{C})$ is sent to must be a diagonal matrix. Ctd in next comment

Comment: ctd: On the other hand we know that there is no surjective map from the algebra of 2-dimensional diagonal matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ onto $\mathbb{H}$ since the dimensions are equal and hence such a surjection would be an isomorphism, but $\mathbb{H}$ does not have two commuting subspaces of complex dimension 1 (real dimension 2) and the 2-by-2 diagonal matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ do. So that is the proof of the second of Kimbal's claims. Still I don't see how to get from a rep of $GL(n, \mathbb{H})$ to one of the surrounding group $GL(2n, \mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Ugh, where I wrote 'the subgroup $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ I meant 'the subgroup $SL(m, \mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will work out the case $n = 2$ in detail. The same proof works for general $n$, I just want to save the labor of typing $n$ by $n$ matrices...

Thus assume that $f:\operatorname M_2 = \operatorname M_2(\Bbb H) \rightarrow \Bbb H$ is a surjective multiplicative map.

> **Lemma 1**. Whenever $A\in \operatorname M_2$ is invertible, the image $f(A)$ is also invertible.

Proof: If $A$ is invertible, then multiplication by $A$ is a bijection on $\operatorname M_2$. Hence $f(A)$ cannot be zero, otherwise $f$ is constantly zero.

> **Lemma 2**. The map $f$ restricted to $\operatorname{GL}_2 = \operatorname{GL}_2(\Bbb H)$ gives a group homomorphism from $\operatorname{GL}_2$ to $\Bbb H^\times$. In particular, we have $f\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = 1$.

Proof: This is clear from Lemma 1.

---

We want to arrive at a contradiction, hence showing that such an $f$ does not exist.

> **Assumption 3**. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $f\begin{pmatrix} & 1\\1 &\end{pmatrix} = 1$.

Note: for general $n$, we have the canonical embedding of the symmetric group $S_n$ into $\operatorname{GL}_n$, and this assumption becomes: $f(\sigma) = 1$ for all $\sigma \in S_n$.

Why we can make this assumption: we have $f(\sigma)^{n!} = f(\sigma^{n!}) = 1$ by Lemma 2, hence by changing $f$ to $f^{n!}$, which is still surjective multiplicative, we may make this assumption.

---

From now on, we always make Assumption 3.

> **Lemma 4**. We have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for any $\lambda \in \Bbb H$.

Proof: This comes from the identity $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} & 1\\1 & \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} & 1\\1 & \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and Assumption 3.

> **Lemma 5**. We have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & z\end{pmatrix} = 1$ for all $z \in \Bbb H^\times$ with $|z| = 1$.

Proof: For any $\lambda, \mu \in \Bbb H^\times$, we have: $$f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\mu\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \mu\end{pmatrix}=f\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \mu\end{pmatrix}=f\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \\ & \mu\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \mu\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}\lambda & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \mu\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \mu\lambda\end{pmatrix}.$$ Therefore we have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\mu\lambda^{-1}\mu^{-1}\end{pmatrix} = 1$. But any $z \in \Bbb H^\times$ with $|z| = 1$ can be written as $\lambda\mu\lambda^{-1}\mu^{-1}$ for some $\lambda, \mu \in \Bbb H^\times$.

> **Lemma 6**. For any $a\in \Bbb R$, the value $f\begin{pmatrix}a & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}$ is real.

Proof: Since the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix}a & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}$ is in the center of $\operatorname M_2$, we have $f(A)f(B) = f(AB) = f(BA) = f(B)f(A)$ for all $B\in \operatorname M_2$. The surjectivity of $f$ then implies that $f(A)$ lies in the center of $\Bbb H$, namely $\Bbb R$.

> **Assumption 7**. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}$ is real for all $a \in \Bbb R$.

Why we can make this assumption: we already have $$\left(f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}\right)^2 = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}a & \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}a & \\ & a\end{pmatrix}\in \Bbb R.$$Therefore, by changing $f$ to $f^2$, we may make this assumption (while still keeping all required properties of $f$, including Assumption 3).

---

From now on, we always make Assumptions 7.

> **Lemma 8**. We have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix}\in \Bbb R$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb H$.

Proof: The case $\lambda = 0$ is covered by Assumption 7. For $\lambda \neq 0$, by Lemma 5 and Assumption 7, we have: $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & |\lambda|\end{pmatrix}f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \frac \lambda {|\lambda|}\end{pmatrix}\in \Bbb R$.

---

> **Lemma 9**. For any $\alpha \in \Bbb H^\times$, we have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Proof: This comes from the identity $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \alpha^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \alpha\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha\\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and the fact that $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\ & \alpha\end{pmatrix}$ is a real number, hence is in the center of $\Bbb H$.

> **Lemma 10**. For any $\alpha \in \Bbb H$, we have $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = 1$.

Proof: Let $h$ be the value of $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$. By Lemma 9, we have $h = f\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = h^2$. By Lemma 1, we get $h = 1$ and Lemma 9 tells us that $f\begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha \\ & 1\end{pmatrix} = 1$ for any $\alpha \in \Bbb H^\times$. The case $\alpha = 0$ is Lemma 2.

> **Conclusion**. The map $f$ takes values in $\Bbb R$ on $\operatorname M_2$, hence is not surjective. We obtain a contradiction.

Proof: Just note that any matrix in $\operatorname M_2$ can be written as a product of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}1 & \alpha \\ & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} & 1 \\1 & \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}1 &  \\ & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$ with $\alpha, \lambda \in \Bbb H$ (by performing "row and column operations").

---

**Final remarks**.

- As claimed in the very beginning, the proof adapts without difficulty to general $n$.
- The continuous assumption is not used. All arguments are algebraic.
- Since it's a proof by contradiction, it doesn't show that any multiplicative map from $\operatorname M_n(\Bbb H)$ to $\Bbb H$ has image in $\Bbb R$. But it is true that any group homomorphism from $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb H)$ to $\Bbb C^\times$ must factorize through $\Bbb R^\times_+$, as the abelianization of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb H)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^\times_+$.

Comment: Very nice proof, great use of proof by contradiction. I only do not agree with the last final remark: the map that you describe *does* give non-negative real entries, as described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3477987/101420. It would be nice to see if an example exists of a non-surjective multiplicative map with actual non-real elements in the image.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, you are right! I didn't think too deeply on that, and automatically thought the determinant could be any complex number.

Comment: @Vincent After thinking more about it, I think there is no example of group homomorphism from $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb H)$ to $\Bbb C^\times$ taking values outside $\Bbb R$. This is because the abelianization of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\Bbb H)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^\times_{> 0}$. More precisely, the homomorphism $\Bbb H^\times \rightarrow \operatorname {GL}_n(\Bbb H)$ sending $z$ to $diag(z, 1, \dotsc, 1)$ induces an isomorphism between the abelianizations. This is not hard to prove, and is in fact known to Dieudonné: it's Theorem 1 here: http://www.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1943__71__27_0.pdf

Comment: Hmm I just concluded that image outside $\mathbb{R}$ *is* possible, see the last remark in my answer. Put more simply: take a homomorphism to $\mathbb{R}_+$, take the log to make it an homomorphism to the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ and wind that around the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$...

Comment: @Vincent Ah, of course, there are non-trivial homomorphisms from $\Bbb R^\times_+$ to $\Bbb C^\times$... It just has to factor through $\Bbb R^\times_+$.

Comment: Thank you for this superb proof WhatsUp. After a while, I started suspecting that the continuity hypothesis wouldn't be necessary in the end, and your proof confirmed it. That is really nice to know. I will accept your answer for this thread. Of course, I would like to thanks @Vincent also for the efforts put into this problem. If only I could share the bounty, it would have been nice..

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance. I believe that we all enjoyed solving and discussing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**This is a modified version of my earlier answer with some gaps filled up, hence the weird numbering**
a
Let $D \subset Mat(2, \mathbb{H})$ denote the group of invertible diagonal matrices. Let $L$ be the group of lower triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal and let $U$ be the group of upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal. Let $G \subset GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ the set of of matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ such that $a \neq 0$ an $d - ca^{-1}b \neq 0$. The set $G$ is open and dense in $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ so that once we understand the image $f(G)$ of $G$ under a continuous multiplicative map, we also understand the image of $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$. Alternatively if you don't like topology you can show that every matrix in $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ can be written as a product of matrices from $G$. The reason for working with $G$ is that every $g \in G$
can be decomposed as

> $g = ldu$ for some $l \in L, d \in D, u \in U \qquad  (1)$

Let's focus on $D$ first.
It has two subgroups  $D_1$ and $D_2$ consisting respectively of the diagonal matrices with a 1 in the lower right corner and those with a 1 in the upper left corner. As a group both $D_1$ and $D_2$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^*$ of course. We draw some conclusions from the group structure of $\mathbb{H}^*$.

> Lemma 0: The group $\mathbb{H}^*$ decomposes as a direct product of topological groups $\mathbb{H}^* \cong SU(2) \times \mathbb{R}_+$ where the cannonical projection onto the second term is just the familiar modulus operator $|.|$ and the subgroup $SU(2)$ appears as the set of elements of norm $1$.
>
> Lemma 0.5 The group $SU(2)$ is almost simple: its only normal subgroups are $\{1\}, \{-1, +1\}$, and $SU(2)$ itself. The quotient $SU(2)/\{-1, 1\}$ is isomorphic to $SO(3)$ which is simple and is *not* isomorphic to any subgroup of $\mathbb{H}$.
>
> Corollary 0.75: every group homomorphism from $\mathbb{H}^*$ to itself maps the $SU(2)$-subgroup of norm 1 elements in the domain either bijectively onto the $SU(2)$-subgroup of norm 1 elements in the codomain or onto the one element subgroup $\{1\}$ in the codomain.
>
> Lemma 1, modified: let $f$ be a multiplicative map from $D \to \mathbb{H}^*$. Then for at least one of the two subgroups $D_1, D_2$ it maps the $SU(2)$-subgroup of norm 1 elements inside that subgroup to $\{1\}$.

Proof: Let $y_1, x_y$ be two non-commuting elements of $SU(2)$ in the codomain $\mathbb{H}$. If $f$ does not map the norm 1 elements in $D_1$ to $1$ then, by corollary 0.75 there is an $x_1 \in D_1$ with $f(x_1) = y_2$. Similarly if $f$ does not map the norm 1 elements in $D_2$ to $1$ then there is a $x_2$ with $f(x_2) = y_2$. Now $x_1x_2 = x_2x_1$ since every element in $D_1$ commutes with every element in $D_2$ but $f(x_1)f(x_2) \neq f(x_2)f(x_1)$, a contradiction.

The question is now what happens to the $\mathbb{R}_+$ subgroup of that group ($D_1$ or $D_2$). I thought that it must be mapped to $\mathbb{R}_+$ in $\mathbb{H}^+$ but that is incorrect, $D_1 \cong \mathbb{H}^*$ can be mapped into a spiral via e.g. $f(x) = e^{(a + bi)\log(|x|)}$ while still sending $SU(2)$ to $\{1\}$, the latter condition being equivalent to $f(x) = f(y)$ whenever $|x| = |y|$ as in lemma 0.

However what we do know is that if the restriction of $f$ maps the $SU(2)$ part of $D_i$ (for some $i \in \{1, 2\}$) to $1$ and hence only depends on its restriction to the $\mathbb{R}_+$ part then $f(x)f(y) = f(y)f(x)$ for every $x,y \in D_i$. It follows that $f(D_i)$ is contained in a two dimensional subalgebra $\mathbb{C}'$ of $\mathbb{H}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Now let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a multiplicative map and let $J = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Since $J^2 = 1$ we have that either $f(J) = 1$ or $f(J) = -1$. But since $JD_1J = D_2$ and vice versa we conclude from Lemma 1 and the above subsequent reasoning that:

> Lemma 2, modified: every multiplicative map $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ maps $D$ into $\mathbb{C}' \backslash \{0\}$ for some 2-dimensional subalgebra $\mathbb{C}' \subset \mathbb{H}$. Moreover $f(D) = f(D_1)$ hence if $f$ is continuous the image $f(D)$ is connected and at most one dimensional.

Progress! Before moving on to $L$ and $U$ we collect some corollaries of this result.

> Corollary 2.5: Let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a multiplicative map and $x = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \in D$. Then $f(x) = f(|x|)$ where $|x| \in D$ is the matrix whose entries are the absolute values of the entries in $x$.

Proof: by Lemma 2 the space $f(D)$ is too small to contain  $SU(2)$, so both the copy of $SU(2)$ inside $D_1$ *and* that in $D_2$ are mapped to 1. The result then follows from Lemma 0.

> Corollary 3 (same result, new proof): Let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a multiplicative map and $q \in D$. Then $f(qxq^{-1}) = f(x)$ for all $x \in GL(2,\mathbb{H})$.

Proof: we distinguish two cases. Either $f(D)  \subset \mathbb{R}$ or it doesn't. In the first case we have that $f(q)$ commutes with $f(x)$ for every $x \in \ GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ and we have $f(qxq^{-1} = f(q)f(x)f(q^{-1} = f(x)f(q)f(q^{-1}) = f(x)$. In the second case  we have a $y \in D$ such that $f(y) \not\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $|y|$ be as in the previous corollary and let $r \in D$ be the matrix whose entries are the square roots of the corresponding entries of $|y|$. We see from the previous corollary that $f(r)^2 = f(y)$. Let $s = r(JrJ)$. Then $s$ is a real scalar multiple of the identity matrix but $f(s) = f(r)^2 = f(y) \not\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $s$ is a real scalar multiple of the identity matrix we have that $sx = xs$ and hence
$$f(s)f(x) = f(x)f(s) \qquad(1.5)$$
for every $x \in GL(2, \mathbb{H})$. But since $f(s)$ is a non-real element of $\mathbb{C}'$, with $\mathbb{C}'$ as in Lemma 2 we find that (1.5) implies that $f(x) \in \mathbb{C}'$ for every $x \in GL(2, \mathbb{H})$. It then follows from lemma 2 that $f(q)f(x) = f(x)f(q)$ for *every* $q \in D$ and the claim of Corollary 3 follows.

From this point on we return to the original argument..

We use corollary 3 to understand the action of $f$ on $U$.

> Lemma 4: let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a multiplicative map and let $u_1, u_2 \in U \backslash \{I\}$. Then $f(u_1) = f(u_2)$.

Proof:
$u_i = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b_i \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for $i = 1, 2$ where $b_1, b_2$ are non-zero, hence invertible, elements of $\mathbb{H}$.

In general we have
$$\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & d^{-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & abd^{-1} \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \qquad (2)$$

Taking $a = b_2, b = d = b_1$ in (2) we obtain $qu_1q^{-1} = u_2$ where $q \in D$ is the diagonal matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ from (2). The claim $f(u_1) = f(u_2)$ then follows from Corollary 3.

> Corollary 5: let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a *continuous* multiplicative map, then $f(U) = \{1\}$.

Proof: by Lemma 4 we have that $f$ takes only one value on $U \backslash \{I\}$ and hence by continuity it should take this same value on $I \in U$ as well. But this means we *know* the unique value that $f$ takes on $U$ because $f(I) = 1$ for *any* multiplicative map.

In a completely analogous way we get:

> Lemma 6: let $f: GL(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}^*$ be a continuous multiplicative map, then $f(L) = \{1\}$.

Now we can prove our main result.

> Theorem 7, modified: let $f: Mat(2, \mathbb{H}) \to \mathbb{H}$ be a continuous multiplicative map, then either $f$ maps every element of $Mat(2, \mathbb{H})$ to zero, or it maps invertible matrices to a one dimensional multiplicative Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{H}^*$ contained in a two dimensional subalgebra $\mathbb{C}'$ of $\mathbb{H}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Proof: We distinguish two cases: either $f(GL(2, \mathbb{H})) \subset \mathbb{H}^*$ or there is some $g \in GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ with $f(g) = 0$. In the latter case we find that $f$ is identically zero as $f(x) = f(xg^{-1}g) = f(xg^{-1})f(g) = f(xg^{-1})0 = 0$ for every $x \in Mat(2, \mathbb{H})$. In the second case, let $g \in GL(2, \mathbb{H})$. As in the text preceding (1) we may assume that $g \in G$, with $G$ defined there. From (1) and Corollary 5 and Lemma 6 we see that there is a $d \in D$ such that $f(g) = f(d)$. Lemma 2 then gives us the claim of the theorem.

I like Theorem 7 because it tells us that yes, non-zero maps may exist, but only under very severe restrictions. To get the full result we only need:

> Lemma 8: The set $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ of invertible matrices is dense (in the topological sense) in the real vectorspace $Mat(2, \mathbb{H})$ of all matrices.
>
> Remark 9: I think that *every* group homomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{H}^*$ is of the form $x \mapsto \exp(\alpha \log x)$ for some  quaternion $\alpha$. (Here $\exp$ is defined by the same power series as always.) Reading my proof with this in mind we find that for non-zero continous multiplicative $f$ we find that there is an $\alpha \in \mathbb{H}$ such that for each $g = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix} \in G$ we have that $f(g) = \exp(\alpha \log(|a||d - ca^{-1}b|))$. Now we can  recognize the expression inside the $\log$ as the determinant of the $(2 \times 2) \times (2 \times 2)$-block matrix $g'$ over $\mathbb{C}$ associated to $g$ in the standard way (i.e. as in your linked question). By continuity we then conclude that $f(g) = \exp(\alpha \log(\det(g')))$ for every $g \in Mat(2, \mathbb{H})$. This then gives a nice classification of all possible $f$ and answers the question about the existence of $f$ with non-real image (e.g. take $\alpha = 2 pi i$).

Comment: Thank you for your proof Vincent. I noticed no flaw in it, so I believe it to be true. You proved a stronger statement than the problem I initially asked in the case of $n=2$. Using your theorem $7$ and if Gauß reduction works over quaternionic matrices (which I am not exactly sure), we can actually drop the continous hypohesis in my initial problem : any multiplicative map from $M_n(\mathbb H)$ (for now, $n=2$) to $\mathbb H$ is not surjective. Indeed, with Gauß reduction we could argue that any matrix is equivalent to $J_r$ (the diagonal matrix with $r$ times the entry $1$ then all $0$)[...]

Comment: [...] and then, by multiplicativity and your theorem $7$, we see that all such maps could only take values inside the union of at most $n$ half-lines inside $\mathbb H$. Each half lines would be directed by the image of $J_r$, for $r$ varying from $1$ to $n$. This would be a really nice result to me ; and it could work for general $n$ provided that we can extend your theorem $7$ and that we can apply Gauß reuduction on quaternionic matrices.

Comment: Unfortunately I noticed that there *is* a flaw, in Lemma 1, although I believe with some extra work we can get back on track from Corollaray 3 onwards. I'll try and edit the answer tonight (European time)

Answer (score 0):

Note: We do have multiplicative from $M_n(\mathbb{H})$ to $\mathbb{H}$, since  $M_n(\mathbb{H}) \subset M_{4n} (\mathbb{R})$, and compose with $\det$, however, the image is $\mathbb{R}$.

First, recall the formula for the product of two [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) using the real and vector part:

$$(r_1 + v_1) \cdot (r_2 + v_2) = r_1 r_2 - \langle v_1, v_2 \rangle + (r_1 v_2 + r_2 v_2 + v_1 \times v_2)$$

It follows that if $q = r+ v \in \mathbb{H} \backslash \mathbb{R}$ ( i. e. $v\ne 0$), then the centralizer is a commutative $R$ subalgebra iso to $\mathbb{C}$:

$$C(q) = \mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R}v \simeq \mathbb{C}\subset \mathbb{H}$$

Say we have a morphism of groups from $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ to $\mathbb{H}^{\times}$. Now, the elements
$$\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right),\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta\end{matrix} \right) $$ commute, for all $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{H}^{\times}$. We claim that this implies

$$\left (\begin{matrix}\alpha \gamma \alpha^{-1} \gamma^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)\mapsto 1 \in \mathbb{H}^{\times}$$

Indeed, if for some $\beta \in \mathbb{H}^{\times}$, the element $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta\end{matrix} \right ) $ does not map to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, then all $\left( \begin{matrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ) $ map to a commutative subgroup. Otherwise,  all $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta\end{matrix} \right ) $ map to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, the center of $\mathbb{H}^{\times}$, and so do the conjugate elements $\left( \begin{matrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ) $.

Now let's see the conjugation :

$$\left( \begin{matrix} \delta & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ) \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right )\cdot \left( \begin{matrix} \delta^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ) =\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & \delta\cdot s \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ) $$

Now, let us recall that every quaternion $\delta$ of norm $1$ is a commutant:
$$|\delta| = 1 \implies \delta = \alpha \gamma \alpha^{-1} \gamma^{-1} $$
in $\mathbb{H}^{\times}$. It follows from the above that if $|s_1| = |s_2|$  then $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & s_1 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right )$, $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & s_2 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right )$ map to the same element.

From here it follows that all $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right )$ map to $1$.

Now, using row reduction, one sees that every matrix in $GL(2, \mathbb{H})$ is of product of matrices of the form

$$\left(\begin{matrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right),\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \beta\end{matrix} \right), \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & s \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix} \right ),\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ t & 1\end{matrix} \right ) $$

Provided that $|\alpha|= |\beta| = 1$, the above matrices map to $1\in \mathbb{H}^{\times}$. Since the diagonal matrices with $\alpha$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ commute, we conclude that the image of the morphism is commutative.